# Logistic Population Models - solving for n

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am given P(0)=1/8*420 000 and the current size of the population P(n) = 0,5 * 420 000.

I also have K = 420 000, the carrying capacity and r = 0,31, the rate of growth per year.

The question is:  how long will it take for population size to reach P(n).

Other than setting up a spreadsheet or an iterative equation on my calculator, I have no idea of how to solve for n. I have searched the net for an answer but no luck as yet.

Please let me know if you have an answer or a reference that I can access.
Thank you!

Comment: You have provided us with parameters for the equation, but not the actual equation. Can you please write down the equation you are trying to solve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you are solving the differential equation $P'(t) = r P(t)(1-\frac{P(t))}{K}$, which is separable, you have an explicit solution given by
$$
P(t)=\dfrac{P(0)K e^{r t}}{K-P(0)+P(0)e^{r t}}.
$$

so you want to compute $t$ in such a way that
$$
\dfrac{\frac 18 K^2 e^{r t}}{K-\frac 18 K + \frac 18 K e^{r t}}=\frac 12 K.
$$

You can see that you can eliminate the K's that are not in the exponential and obtain
$$
\frac{e^{r t}}{7 + e^{r t}}= \frac 12\Leftrightarrow e^{r t}=7 \Leftrightarrow t=\frac{\ln 7}{r}
$$

Comment: You're right @LutzL, I'll edit my post.

Comment: Thank you Pierre,  so so much for this succinct solution - much appreciated!